# C Makefile - How to avoid redundant mentions of file names

Tags: c, makefile

For an assignment in one of my classes we need to create a makefile for our C program that's more complex than just `compile: gcc whatever`. I believe we're expected to do something like this:

```
outputname: file1.o file2.o file3.o file4.o
    gcc -o outputname file1.o file2.o file3.o file4.o

clean:
    rm -f outputname file1.o file2.o file3.o file4.o

file1.o: file1.c
    gcc -c file1.c

file2.o: file2.c
    gcc -c file2.c

file3.o: file3.c
    gcc -c file3.c

file4.o: file4.c
    gcc -c file4.c
```

But having to list the same file names multiple times irritates me. If I need to update a name I need to ensure I replace each instance of it in the file. Or if I add a file I have to add new lines that are practically identical to four others already in the file. I've managed to get really close to the functionality of the above makefile:

```
files := file1.o file2.o file3.o file4.o
output := outputname

$(output): $(files)
    gcc -o $(output) $(files)

clean: 
    rm -f $(output) $(files)

$(files): $(files:.o=.c)
    gcc -c $(@:.o=.c)
```

The only difference I can tell is that unlike the first example, this will recompile all of the c files if any one of them has been updated, removing one of the advantages of makefiles. Is there something else I can do that will remove the redundancy but keep all the functionality?

Comment: Remove your last rule and replace with: `%.o: %.c\n\tgcc -c $<\n`

Comment: Aside: You can de-clutter some more by learning about `$@`, `$^` and `$<`. e,g, you might have `$(output): $(files)\n\tgcc -o $@ $^`

Comment: Note that you should be compiling with warning flags — `-Werror -Wall -Wextra` would be a good start (you can get fussier later).  Use macros — especially for things like compiler flags (and even compiler names): `CC = gcc` and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most `make` utilities already have built-in implicit dependencies for things like generating a .o file from a .c file. So since you're not specifying anything special in your compile steps, you condense your file down to something like:

```
OBJS = file1.o file2.o file3.o file4.o

outputname: $(OBJS)
    gcc -o outputname $(OBJS)
```

...and it can handle the rest on its own (oh--except that you'll probably still want your `clean:` rule).

Comment: Would recommend `gcc -o $@ $^`. I've seen makefiles on this site in recent weeks that were like `foo: bar\n\tgcc -o baz waldo`.

Comment: @pmacfarlane: I generally recommend keeping the Makefile as simple as possible, and letting make just do its thing when possible. Add more when you need to do something that won't accomplish.

Comment: @pmacfarlane is right, except you should really go even further and use `$(CC) -o $@ $^` in the recipe for `outputname`, or even use the complete `$(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)` to be fully standard.  It's an important best practice to use the `$@` automatic variable as the target to be built when writing makefile rules, and it's best to use the standard variables everywhere instead of using them in some places (like the built-in rules) but hardcoding things like `gcc` in other places.  That's how obscure errors crop up later.